# ansible: PLAY RECAP: What do these numbers mean?

Tags: ansible

After running an Ansible playbook with the `ansible-playbook` command, I get an output as below.

What exactly do these numbers mean? What is the unit of these numbers? For example, when it says `ok=18`, does it mean 18 tasks?

```
 ____________
< PLAY RECAP >
 ------------

localhost                  :
    ok=18   changed=8    unreachable=0    failed=0    
    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That output means that:

- 18 tasks have been executed without errors, including tasks that did not change something and tasks that changed something.
- 8 tasks have been executed and they did change something on the hosts.
- 4 tasks haven't been executed because the condition in `when` was false.
- 2 tasks have been executed with error but they had `ignore_errors: true`.

Comment: If they didn't change nothing, how many were changed?

Comment: Changed will be 0 and will be "OK"

Comment: I'm running Ansible 6.5.0 and in the recap `ok` definitely includes the number  of `changed` tasks as well.